# Filter columns with multiple values based on list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R which contains a column with a county identifier such as "Los Angeles", "Riverside", etc. However, some rows include multiple counties as string in the county identifier column such as "Santa Barbara, Ventura, Kern".

| type | countyid |
| --- | --- |
| first | Los Angeles |
| second | San Diego |
| third | Santa Barbara, Ventura, Kern |
| second | Riverside |

I am tryingto filter my dataframe based on a list of counties as seen below:

```
coastal <- c("Orange", "San Diego", "Los Angeles", "Santa Barabara")
```

I was able to use the below to filter but it only works on rows with one item in the county identifier column and I need to select rows that include at least one item in the list.

```
coastal_df <- df[df$countyid %in% coastal,]
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer seems not to work. Maybe there is some misunderstanding.
Also, In your

> coastal <- c("Orange", "San Diego", "Los Angeles", "Santa Barabara")

You seem to mistype `"Barbara"` as `"Barabara"`, so even if the code is correct you don't get the match.

According to what I understand, you wants to detect rows with `countyid` containing any county involved in `coastal`. In this case, the key row is "third".

Honestly, it is not a good practice to have column `countyid` containing multiple values, and you are advised to split those rows into seperate ones (see below). Then you can detect values regularly using your code.

```
df%<>% separate_rows(countyid, sep = ", ")%>%as.data.frame()
```

This usually won't hurt your data. However, if you don't want to modify your dataset. Try the regex method at run time:

```
apply(df, 1, 
      function(x) {if(str_detect(coastal,  str_replace_all(x['countyid'], ",", '|'))%>%any()) x})%>%
  t()%>%as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks Joy, Yes the answer I provided was what I had tried, and I found it didn't work. I was trying to avoid splitting the county_id column as this data is provided by state and could include any number of counties (sometimes up to 10). Sorry about the misspelling.

Comment: @Thomas Is there any errors? It does work on my test. I did not split the value in the result, but just at the detecting operation. Did you notice that typo in your coastal vector and correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with base R:

```
df[grepl(paste(coastal, collapse = "|"), df$countyid),]
```

Or using dplyr/tidyverse packages:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(countyid, paste(coastal, collapse = "|")))
```

You could also split the countyid strings, and process them that way. There's a couple of ways you could do that:

- Use `str_split()` on `countyid`, then use `map`, `lapply`, or `setdiff` to find rows with an overlap
- use `separate_longer_delim()` to split the column on commas, then either select rows the way you were originally intending, or if you want to get all rows for a type with a coastal county, group by type, then check if any county within each group is in the coastal county vector.